# AWS Lambda Node.js function Can't Access Aurora MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I have a Node.js (ver 16) app in a Lambda Function and I run it on my local machine fine, however when I run the function on AWS I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'mailQueue'@'172.31.40.76' (using password: YES)",
  "trace": [
    "Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'mailQueue'@'172.31.40.76' (using password: YES)",
    "    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)",
    "    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)",
    "    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)",
    "    at Parser._parsePacket (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)",
    "    at Parser.write (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)",
    "    at Protocol.write (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)",
    "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)",
    "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)",
    "    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)",
    "    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)",
    "    --------------------",
    "    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)",
    "    at Protocol.handshake (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)",
    "    at PoolConnection.connect (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)",
    "    at Pool.getConnection (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:15:10)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1028:29)"
  ]
}
```

The Aurora Security group allows connections from 172.31.0.0/16 and the reachability analyser gives it the ok.

So it appears to be mySQL having issues. The user appears to have correct permissions from any host.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mailQueue'

> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `mailQueue`@`%`
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `emailTransactions`.* TO `mailQueue`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Any suggestions from anyone?

Confirmed all settings with manuals and searched the net, I'm stumped.

Comment: That error indicates that the password being used by Lambda to authenticate with Aurora is incorrect.

Comment: The password works fine when run locally

Comment: Well it's definitely not a network connection error, because you're getting a message back from the database server. And you don't have a host/ip restriction on the user account. What else could it be?

Comment: from the AWS documentation: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.troubleshooting.html

`The Secrets Manager secret used by the proxy doesn't match the user name and password of an existing database user. Either update the credentials in the Secrets Manager secret, or make sure the database user exists and has the same password as in the secret. `

Comment: This might also help: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-access-denied/

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyB. I have tried those and no joy, I have escalated to my account manager.

Comment: I'd suggest to post the question on https://repost.aws/